# Balancing a redox reaction with only one product

Tags: redox, stoichiometry

Consider the following comproportionation reaction:

$$\ce{NH4NO3 -> N2}$$

How would I go about balancing this using the half reaction/ion-electron method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the the same product species in both half -reactions. In the example you gave, this is $\ce{N2}$.

$$\ce{NH4NO3-> N2}$$

The half-reactions are constructed from the ammonium and nitrate ions separately, since these feature nitrogen in different oxidation states:

\begin{align}
\ce{NH4+ &-> N2} \tag{1} \\
\ce{NO3- &-> N2} \tag{2}
\end{align}

Balancing the reduction half-equation $(1)$:

\begin{align}
\ce{2NO3- &-> N2} & & \text{(balance N)} \\
\ce{2NO3- &-> N2 \color{red}{+ 6H2O}} & & \text{(add } \ce{H2O} \text{ to balance O)} \\
\ce{2NO3- \color{red}{+ 12H+} &-> N2 + 6H2O} & & \text{(add } \ce{H+} \text{ to balance H)} \\
\ce{2NO3- + 12H+ \color{red}{+ 10e-} &-> N2 + 6H2O} & & \text{(add } \ce{e-} \text{ to balance charge / oxidation state)}
\end{align}

And balancing the oxidation half-reaction:

\begin{align}
\ce{2NH4+ &-> N2} & & \text{(balance N)} \\
\ce{2NH4+ &-> N2 \color{red}{+ 8H+}} & & \text{(add } \ce{H+} \text{ to balance H)} \\
\ce{2NH4+ &-> N2 + 8H+ \color{red}{+ 8e-}} & & \text{(add } \ce{e-} \text{ to balance charge / oxidation state)} \\
\end{align}

In order to combine the two balanced half-equations, we need to multiply the first by $4$ and the second by $5$:

\begin{align}
\ce{8NO3- + 48H+ + 40e- &-> 4N2 + 24H2O} \\
\ce{10NH4+ &-> 5N2 + 40H+ + e-} \\ \hline
\ce{8NO3- + 10NH4+ + 48H+ + 40e- + 10H2O &-> 9N2 + 24H2O + 40H+ + 40e-}
\end{align}

which finally reduces to

$$\ce{8NO3- + 10NH4+ + 8H+ -> 9N2 + 14H2O}.$$